# Join 3 tables in Symfony2

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with some query in Symfony2, I have 3 entites (they are simplified a bit):

```
class Group
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupMember", mappedBy="family") */
    protected $groupMembers;


class GroupMember
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="group_member_type", type="integer")
     */
    protected $groupMemberType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="groupMembers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $group;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="memberships")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $user;
```

USER -> standard FOSuserbundle user

I want to make query that returns All groups where current user is a group member. Could someone tell me how to do that?

Here is my try:

```
SELECT g FROM (group g INNER JOIN groupmember gm ON g.id=gm.group_id) INNER JOIN fos_user u ON gm.user_id = u.id WHERE u.id = 6
```

but it returns

```
Unknown column 'g' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Could you precise the relations between your entities ?

Comment: Any reason you're not using Doctrine's query builder?

Comment: No, there is no difference for me between query builder and createQuery, but the problem is that I can't write right query neither in sql nor in query builder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Query Builder, assuming you've fetched the user and stored it in `$userObject` and your bundle name is `BundleName`:

```
$groups = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('g')
    ->from('BundleName:Group', 'g')
    ->innerJoin('g.groupMembers', 'gm')
    ->innerJoin('gm.user', 'u')
    ->where('u = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $userObject)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

You also need to make sure that your relational mappings are correct.

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupMember", mappedBy="family") */
protected $groupMembers;
```

should be

```
/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupMember", mappedBy="group") */
protected $groupMembers;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is right query:

```
SELECT g.* FROM (group g INNER JOIN groupmember gm ON g.id=gm.group_id) INNER JOIN fos_user u ON gm.user_id = u.id WHERE u.id = 6
```